# Change the format of a dataframe which has two types of date formats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data frame column that looks like this:

```
df['Column_Name']
1   25/09/2019
2   26/09/2019
3   28/09/2019
4   2019-01-08 00:00:00
5   2019-02-08 00:00:00
```

The date type is object, I try to change using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Column_Name'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 8, 0, 0) does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match).
```

I want to have these result:

```
1   25/09/2019
2   26/09/2019
3   28/09/2019
4   01/08/2019
5   02/08/2019
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.to_datetime(df['Column_Name'], infer_datetime_format=True)` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the result is not the desired:
The dates from the rows 4 and 5 have to be changed, please look the difference between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df
           Column_Name
0           25/09/2019
1           26/09/2019
2           28/09/2019
3  2019-01-08 00:00:00
4  2019-02-08 00:00:00

>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Column_Name'], errors='coerce')
0   2019-09-25
1   2019-09-26
2   2019-09-28
3   2019-01-08
4   2019-02-08
Name: dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the result is not the desired:
The dates from the rows 4 and 5 have to be changed, please look the difference between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy.